# I dont see Configure workflow manager with settings on config wizard

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow-manager

I am trying to upgrade SharePoint 2010 workflow manager to SharePoint 2013 workflow manager.

There was a caption "SharePoint 2013 is not available because the workflow service is not configured" on SharePoint designer 2013.

Comment: Please tag with which version of SharePoint you are using.

Comment: SharePoint 2019 on - premise

Comment: You need to setup another server to host Workflow Services:  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/governance/install-and-configure-workflow-for-sharepoint-server

Comment: I was trying to configure on SharePoint server but thank you for heads up